# Speed up byte parsing possible?

Tags: c#, performance

We are doing some performance optimizations in our project and with the profiler I came upon the following method:

```
private int CalculateAdcValues(byte lowIndex)
{
    byte middleIndex = (byte)(lowIndex + 1);
    byte highIndex = (byte)(lowIndex + 2);

    // samples is a byte[]
    retrun (int)((int)(samples[highIndex] << 24) 
        + (int)(samples[middleIndex] << 16) + (int)(samples[lowIndex] << 8));
}
```

This method is already pretty fast with ~1µs per execution, but it is called ~100.000 times per second and so it takes ~10% of the CPU.

**Does anyone have an idea how to further improve this method?**

EDIT:

**Current solution:**

```
fixed (byte* p = samples)
{
    for (; loopIndex < 61; loopIndex += 3)
    {
        adcValues[k++] = *((int*)(p + loopIndex)) << 8;
    }
}
```

This takes <40% of the time then before (the "whole method" took ~35µs per call before and ~13µs now). The `for`-loop actualy takes more time then the calcualtion now...

Comment: Why the casts to `byte`? Do you need to reduce indices mod 256? The casts to `int` are useless since the shifting already extended the values to `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing that you have a friendly endianess, go `unsafe`

```
unsafe int CalculateAdcValuesFast1(int lowIndex)
{
  fixed (byte* p = &samples[lowIndex])
  {
    return *(int*)p << 8;
  }
}
```

On x86 about 30% faster. Not much gain as I hoped. About 40% when on x64.

As suggested by @CodeInChaos:

```
  var bounds = samples.Length - 3;
  fixed (byte* p = samples)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
    {
      var r = CalculateAdcValuesFast2(p, i % bounds); // about 2x faster
      // or inlined:
      var r = *((int*)(p + i % bounds)) << 8; // about 3x faster
      // do something
    }
  }


unsafe object CalculateAdcValuesFast2(byte* p1, int p2)
{
  return *((int*)(p1 + p2)) << 8;
}
```

Comment: I think the gain is larger if you move the fixing one level up in the call hierarchy.

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour if `lowIndex == samples.Length-3` unlike the OP's code. It also relies on the system being little-endian.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Thats why I said it is endian friendly :) And no, not seeing any undefined behavior. It just wont throw an exception if you go out of bounds, like the safe version will. But you should be taking care of the in the `for` condition already.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: What is the likelyhood of running this code on a big-endian processor? What big-endian processors does .NET run on in the wild? Maybe Mon with a mainframe? I would be using C or assembler then :)

Comment: @CodesInChaos: +1 for the first comment though, about 50% speed up, but now my version stays the same speed as the safe version...

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Added your suggestions and expected performance. Almost 3 times faster :)

Comment: Reading beyond the end of the array is undefined behaviour. Could cause access violations/segfaults for certain array sizes. The OP's code works and doesn't throw any exception for `lowIndex == samples.Length - 3`, but your code reads one byte beyond the end in that case.

Answer (score 5):

I strongly suspect that after casting to `byte`, your indexes are being converted back to `int` anyway for use in the array indexing operation. That will be cheap, but may not be entirely free. So get rid of the casts, unless you were using the conversion to `byte` to effectively get the index within the range 0..255. At that point you can get rid of the separate local variables, too.

Additionally, your casts to `int` are no-ops as the shift operations are only defined on `int` and higher types.

Finally, using `|` may be faster than `+`:

```
private int CalculateAdcValues(byte lowIndex)
{
    return (samples[lowIndex + 2] << 24) |
           (samples[lowIndex + 1] << 16) |
           (samples[lowIndex] << 8);

}
```

(Why is there nothing in the bottom 8 bits? Is that deliberate? Note that the result will end up being negative if `samples[lowIndex + 2]` has its top bit set - is that okay?)

Comment: ~50% faster then before, but we went with the `unsafe` solution from leppie as it is even faster...

Comment: @"Why is there nothing in the bottom 8 bits?": We ave 32 bit integers but we only get the top 24 bit from the hardware to save bandwidth as it is accurate enough for our purpose.

Answer (score 0):

May be following can be little faster. I have removed casting to integer.

```
        var middleIndex = (byte)(lowIndex + 1);
        var highIndex = (byte)(lowIndex + 2);

        return (this.samples[highIndex] << 24) + (this.samples[middleIndex] << 16) + (this.samples[lowIndex] << 8);
```